# Create a function to loop through data table variables and add counts

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to create a function that inserts new column in a data table with the counts for each variable in the list given as parameter.

Here is a working code, but it is not a function:

```
a = data.table(x=c(1,2,3,3,1), y=c(3,4,4,23,3))
setkey(a, "x", "y")
a[,x_cnt := .N, by=list(x)]
a[,y_cnt := .N, by=list(y)]
> a
   x  y x_cnt y_cnt
1: 1  3     2     2
2: 1  3     2     2
3: 2  4     1     2
4: 3  4     2     2
5: 3 23     2     1
```

Here is my code so far:

```
a = data.table(x=c(1,2,3,3,1), y=c(3,4,4,23,3))
my.f1cnt <- function(ds, variable_list)
{
    for(var in variable_list)
    {
        setkey(ds, var)
        ds[,paste0(var, "_cnt") := .N, by=list(var)]
    }
    #return
    ds
}

my.f1cnt(a, c("x","y"))
Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose) : 
  some columns are not in the data.table: var
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with setkeyv:

```
my.f1cnt <- function(ds, variable_list)
{
    for(var in variable_list)
    {
        setkeyv(ds, var)
        ds[,paste0(var, "_cnt") := .N, by=var]
    }
    #return
    ds
}
a = data.table(x=c(1,2,3,3,1), y=c(3,4,4,23,3))
my.f1cnt(a, c("x","y"))
```

Comment: Note that there's no need to `setkey(v)` at all for aggregation (and is usually much faster).